# Create a github page with index.html already present

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a [Github project](https://github.com/blunderboy/stackeye) which is used to watch questions on stackoverflow and other stackexchange sites. After watching questions, you can get notifications for new answers/comments on that question.

This project already contains an `index.html` file. Now, I am trying to create a **github page** for that project. Since, github page also needs an `index.html`, so that will override my current `index.html` which is used in the project. How do I prevent this situation so that my github page `index.html` does not affect `index.html` used in the project. ?

I have already creates gh-pages branch like this

```
git checkout -b gh-pages
```

PS: I don't want to rename index.html used in chrome-extension. That will be my last option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move your source into a subdirectory (many projects have a directory called `src` for this) you shouldn't have any conflicts.

Your new repository structure might look something like this:

```
docs/
src/
    content_scripts/
    images/
    libs/
    ItemSelector.js
    ...
    index.html (this is the existing file)
    ...
.gitignore
index.html (this is the new gh-pages file)
README.md
```